# Replacing image pixel in Java2D

Tags: java, java-2d

I am trying to replace some pixels from my source image(PNG format). But i am end up with some confusing result. Basically i am replacing a particular RGB values with black and white colors. Here is my code,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ChangePixel
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "D4635.png");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);

    int[] replaceColors = new int[2];
    replaceColors[0] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
    replaceColors[1] = Color.WHITE.getRGB();
    Color src = new Color(133, 101, 51);
    int srcRGBvalue = src.getRGB();

    changeAlg2(image, srcRGBvalue, replaceColors);
}

private static void changeAlg2(BufferedImage image, int srcRGBvalue, int[] replaceColors) throws IOException
{
    for (int width = 0; width < image.getWidth(); width++)
    {
        for (int height = 0; height < image.getHeight(); height++)
        {
            if (image.getRGB(width, height) == srcRGBvalue)
            {
                image.setRGB(width, height, ((width + height) % 2 == 0 ? replaceColors[0] : replaceColors[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "107.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
}
}
```

It changes my source pixels to black and some other color, instead of white. Please advice me, what's going wrong here.

Since this is my first post, I can't able to attach my images. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Edit: I have uploaded the source and the output images in a site. Here is the URL,
Source : http://s20.postimage.org/d7zdt7kwt/D4635.png
Output : http://s20.postimage.org/kdr4vntzx/107.png
Expected output : After the black pixel, white pixel has to come.

Edit : Resolved code as per **Jan Dvorak** advice,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ChangePixel
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "D12014.gif");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);

    Color src = new Color(223, 170, 66);
    int srcRGBvalue = src.getRGB();
    int[] replaceColors = new int[2];
    replaceColors[0] = Color.MAGENTA.getRGB();
    replaceColors[1] = Color.CYAN.getRGB();

    changeAlg2(image, srcRGBvalue, replaceColors);
}

private static void changeAlg2(BufferedImage image, int srcRGBvalue, int[] replaceColors) throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int width = 0; width < image.getWidth(); width++)
    {
        for (int height = 0; height < image.getHeight(); height++)
        {
            if (image.getRGB(width, height) == srcRGBvalue)
            {
                image2.setRGB(width, height, ((width + height) % 2 == 0 ? replaceColors[0] : replaceColors[1]));
            }
            else
            {
                image2.setRGB(width, height, image.getRGB(width, height));
            }
        }
    }

    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "110.gif");
    ImageIO.write(image2, "gif", file);
}
}
```

Regards
Raja.

Comment: Does the image use a pallete (that excludes white), by any chance?

Comment: Hi Jan, that's a PNG image. That's what I know. I don't know whether it's using palette color or not. I am sorry. Even if i'm replace the targeted colors to something else like Green and Red, I can see only Green. The second color is missing.

Comment: What if you use White and Black instead of Black and White?

Comment: Jan, i've replaced the colors as "replaceColors[0] = Color.RED.getRGB(); replaceColors[1] = Color.BLUE.getRGB();". But it's not using any of these colors. Instead it's using the colors which is inside the image. I guess it's using the palette color.

Comment: The logic seems correct to me, but you may need to set true-color manually.

Comment: Jan you are correct. It's using Indexed color (256 colors).

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can I set the true-color manually. Any code samples would be great. Also please tell that, for an indexed image how do I add new color to the indexed palette, if it's not there already. Or how can I convert the indexed palette color to direct pixel values.

Comment: If I knew, I'd write an answer.

Comment: For starters, you could _save_ the image as true-color (24bit).

Comment: I'm going to write an answer. The API is not perfect but it will do.

Comment: Can you store the image with less than 256 colors in the pallete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding colors that are not present in the original image palette, the pixels you are trying to set are clipped to the nearest color in the palette. You need to set a new color mode. Either convert to 24bpp RGB (true-color) or extend the palette with the new colors.

It doesn't seem to be possible to modify an existing `BufferedImage` `ColorModel` or assign a new one, but you can create a new buffer and copy the data there. Creating a new `BufferedImage` with the same `Raster` might work as well (only if the bit depth does not change?).

If you don't mind, you can always create a True-color image. try:

```
{
    BufferedImage old = image;
    image = new BufferedImage(
        old.getWidth(),
        old.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
    image.setData(old.getRaster());
} // old is no longer needed
```

API reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

You could try to detect if the image is already in true-color (`image.getColorModel() instanceof ???`) to avoid having to copy the buffer when not needed.

You could try to extend the existing palette. If that is not possible (there is no palette to start with or there is not enough space), you have to fallback to RGB.

See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html (getColorModel and the constructor taking a ColorModel and type)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html (getMapSize, getRGBs and the corresponding constructor)

From seeing your actual palette, you'll need some sort of deduplication logic because your palette is already 256 bytes - the maximum size of a PNG palette. Note that you should not save the image with larger palette than there are colors in the image (especially when you want to add new colors later). your original file could have been saved with a 2-color palette, saving 762 bytes.

Note that you don't gain much from storing the image as indexed as opposed to true-color with the same number of colors. The reason is that the byte stream (palette = 1 byte per pixel, true-color = 3 or 4 bytes per pixel) is losslessly compressed (with DEFLATE) anyways. Indexed can save you a few bytes (or lose you a few bytes, if the palette is big), but it won't reduce the file size to one third.

Comment: Thank you Jan, as per your advice I've created a new BufferedImage instance and it's resolved.

Comment: Jan, I have one more question. If an indexed palette contains some free room to add new color, how can I add the same.

Comment: @Sivagururaja If the palette has some free room, then you can preallocate space (existing palette size + number of colors you're adding), extract the palette from the color model, add your own colors to the end, construct the new color model and use the color model in the new buffered image constructor. Then you just copy the data to the new buffer.